# Home button, Notification Bar, and Recent Tabs not working

Tags: hardware, 7.1-nougat, cache, softkey

I have an Asus Zenfone 4 Max with Android 7.1.1 OS and the home button doesn't seem to be reacting with the software (probably ZenUI Launcher) because it doesn't work or go back to the home screen but it does vivrate and make the fingerprint sensor work, the Notification Bar is not working because i can't drag it down totally only partially. I only know it was turned off and charged and then when it was turned on those things didn't work.(friend's phone so i don't have much info) As to what I have tried is the following: Updating phone, Forcing stop ZenUI Launcher, clearing cache date, clearing cache partition(i believe, only took a second so not sure) and that's about it. Im trying to look for an alternative solution from Factory Reseting it so that wouldbn't be an option unless it's the only solution. Sorry for little info but any idea on how to fix this will be appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Same what I found that could work for you if wipe partition cache. It doesnt erase apps,pics etc. I find this issues with older models and some were fix going to restore mode (hold vol up + power when starting phone then choose) and chossing wipe partition cache. My cel is max 4 too. I hope this helps and if yu fix it let me know.